# Count number of "registered" entries, grouped by date, that had a "purchase" event within X days of registration date

Tags: mysql

I've got a table like this:

| id | timestamp | email | ip | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-15 00:01:00 | demo@demo.com | 11.11.11.11 | Registration |
| 2 | 2021-07-15 00:04:00 | demo@demo.com | 11.11.11.11 | Purchase |
| 3 | 2021-07-15 00:07:00 | test@test.com | 22.22.22.22 | Registration |
| 4 | 2021-07-15 00:08:00 | someone@else.com | 33.33.33.33 | Registration |
| 5 | 2021-07-16 00:01:00 | test@test.com | 22.22.22.22 | Purchase |
| 6 | 2021-07-16 00:02:00 | someone@else.com | 33.33.33.33 | Purchase |

That keeps track of all users' emails, their IP, date/time and events (Registration & Purchase).

Now, I am trying to run daily tally of a) registrations, and b) conversions (purchases happened within 7 days of registering, assigned to the initial registration date for that email/IP, not the purchase date).

I can figure out the a) registrations easily... but trying to figure out how to query conversions within 7 days AND then assign those for each registration to the registration date (instead of the conversion date, which would be easy), is proving to be quite a challenge.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, 
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS registrations,
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conversions
FROM click_tracking
WHERE DATE(timestamp) <= '2021-07-31'
AND DATE(timestamp) >= '2021-07-01' 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This gives me the following result:

| date | registrations | conversions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-15 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-07-16 | 0 | 2 |

and what I would ideally need is this (the 3 Purchase events are tied to the 3 Registration events on the 15th, hence why 3 conversions are assigned to 15th, and none to the 16th):

| date | registrations | conversions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-15 | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-07-16 | 0 | 0 |

Makes sense?

And keep in mind that this click_tracking table is million or two records in size, and I've already crashed it a few times trying to use JOINS on itself, so not just any query will do either...

Any idea how to go about this efficiently and change my query to accomplish this?

Comment: Will the event will always be `Registration` followed with `Purchase` for every session? And what would be the unique identifier? email+ip?

Comment: The "Registration" is always going to be a starting event, but "Purchase" is optional, and it will be recorded only for about 10-20% of all Registration events, so no, it is not to be expected after every Registration, but IT IS expected AFTER the Registration, not BEFORE, if that's what you mean. And the unique identifier is EMAIL field. Hope that helps.

Comment: Something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=974f040f0b717a667fe75b9e184cd746

Comment: Umm, yeah,... ish. The only thing it's missing is the condition for the "Purchase" being within 7 days of a "Registration" for it to count towards the total sum of purchases. How / where would you add that in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need window functions for this type of query:

```sql
WITH combined AS (
  SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date0,
  email,
  FIRST_VALUE(event) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS event1,
  NTH_VALUE(event,2) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS event2,
  FIRST_VALUE(date(timestamp)) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS date1,
  NTH_VALUE(DATE(timestamp),2) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS date2
FROM click_tracking
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-30 23:59:59')
SELECT date0 AS date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN event1='Registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS registrations,
  SUM(CASE WHEN event1='Registration' AND event2='Purchase' AND DATEDIFF(date2,date1) < 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conversions
FROM combined
GROUP BY 1
```

Assuming that for every email the first record is always a `Registration` and the second record (if any) is always a `Purchase`, you get the type and date for the first 2 records at once. Then you can easily count the registrations and purchases separately, at the same time applying the additional filter condition for no more than 7 days of distance between the 2 events.

If you have a key on `timestamp` the query should be fast enough even with 1M rows.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting all zeroes in "conversions" column, all across the board, no matter how I tweak that query...

Comment: If you try with the [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=48e2cb233d459996c1c6a9ccb6d519d5) you should see non-zero conversions.

Comment: Ahh, I realized why that is - I've got multiple entries with other event names under same emails, so once I added another WHERE condition to only single those two event types out with AND event IN ('Registration', 'Purchase'), it returned the data I was looking for. Thank you! This is amazing, and I never even know of such possibilities in mySQL... gonna be reading up a bit more on these functions.